# Generate multiple HTML elements from JSON using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How to use Jquery and Javascript to extract JSON from $ajax and then do a foreach, and create a string that will append to html DOM?

Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Companies/GetSearchRatios",
    context: this,
    success: function (data) {
       //return JSON
    }
});
```

Result JSON

```
[{"name":"MyNAme","value":350},{"name":"Hello","value":356}]
```

I can easily acces this values inside $ ajax method success, but how can I extract this value outside of method and use it to append to DOM?

This is what I need as a result of some for/foreach method:

```
  var $gElemRatios =
    '<option value=""></option>' +
    '<option value="350">MyNAme</option>' +
    '<option value="356">Hello</option>';
```

Then I use this var to combine with another:

```
 var $gElem =
    '<div class="cbox cboxQuarterWidth">' +
         '<select id="combobox_0">' +
               $gElemRatios + // here I add previous generated elem
         '</select>' +
    '</div>';
```

And finally:

```
$("#main").append($gElem);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to loop through the data passed to the success handler:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Companies/GetSearchRatios",
    context: this,
    success: function (data) {
       $.each(data,function(){
          console.log(this.name); //just an example how to access things
          $('#select').text(this.value); //maybe?
       });
    }
});
```

See this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zDJez/)**

Comment: ok, great, how can i create string as show in question and get this var outside of success method?

Comment: I need this string as a var, global, I cannot directly append data to DOM, because of other things...

Comment: @Ingol create an array or object in the scope that you need and use it to store your data.

Comment: well I thing this is my main problem, together with creating multiple strings, because of success asynchronous, my scope is undefined?

Comment: No that should not be the problem. See: http://jsfiddle.net/zDJez/1/ for a basic approach. Also see the cat example here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: @Ingol I guess your problem is not a scope one, but you will probably try to fill your content before the ajax call has finished. So - even if you store the data outside of the ajax call - just trigger the content update at the end of the success handler

Comment: @m90- I see your point, but i need a global var, filled with data on document.ready, not to call json every time... Can you make an example to answer my queastion, i am not advanced id Jquery?

Comment: @Ingol How do you expect the data to be available on `$(document).ready` when you're making an AJAX call? Instead replace your `$(document).ready` handler with a `init` function that is triggered by the success handler of the AJAX call: http://jsfiddle.net/dNncy/1/